# how to iterate through rows based on unique column values and sample data using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

[image]

This is the Pivot table of my sample data.. as you can see there are 551 rows which is dynamic. Sampling % is dynamic (logic is already in place). Sampling count is calculated by dividing count with sampling%. Now Lets pick one example.. for bmallik@fyhomes.com .. it has 60 rows and out of which total 12 rows need to be picked for sampling based on sampling count every fifth row needs to be picked. since the count is 551 the sampling needs to start from first row. if it was 553 sampling need to start from 3rd row and so on. For each user in pivot table sampling needs to be performed as per sampling% and sampling count as explained earlier. I need to do this using VBA. can anyone help in implementing this logic or help me with suitable approach.

Comment: Isn't that the third time you are asking that?

Comment: @FunThomas Yes.. this time I have framed my question better.. coz last time my question was closed stating its not clear